# Viewing List Data via CQWP, need XSLT to modify the content look in CQWP Webpart

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

Viewing List Data via CQWP, need XSLT to modify the content look in CQWP Webpart

Detailed explanation:

- I've created a List and its working fine.
- Created a CQWP webpart to fetch the List data and show on the Intranet homepage.
- Data even appears. However, need the data in a different format.

Example: Column3 - Column 1 - (Column2)

After minutes of google, understood it can be achieved using XSLT.
Any suggestion if a better alternate for non coders.
If not, guidance on how to get the stuff done in XSLT for non coders?

Answer (score 2):

Without XSLT you cannot change the view of list in Content Query Web Part. XSLT don't include any tough scripting and coding it is just formatting like table tag.

Please refer this link to get more details explanation [Modifying XSLT for CQWP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St)

Thanks

Comment: How can i get the data viewed in the format as shown above in my first post.